# common commands between docker images

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I've 4 images which they do not share the same basic image :

```
image1 : FROM openjdk:8  
image2 : FROM mongo:3.6  
image3 : FROM ssh  
image4 : FROM ubuntu
```

But at some point I've to execute the same commands on all of them, ex:

```
RUN useradd -s /bin/bash -p $(openssl passwd -1 user) -d /home/user -m -G sudo user
USER user
WORKDIR /home/user

RUN mkdir -p /home/user/.ssh/ && \
    chmod 0700 /home/user/.ssh  && \
    touch /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys && \
    chmod 600 /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys && \
    touch /home/user/.ssh/config && \
    chmod 600 /home/user/.ssh/config

COPY ssh-keys/ /keys/
RUN cat /keys/id_rsa.pub >> /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys
RUN cat /keys/config >> /home/user/.ssh/config
```

and having the same directories structure :

```
image1  
--->ssh-keys  
------>config  
------>id_rsa  
------>id_rsa.pub  
--->Dockerfile

image2  
--->ssh-keys  
------>config  
------>id_rsa  
------>id_rsa.pub  
--->Dockerfile

image3  
--->ssh-keys  
------>config  
------>id_rsa  
------>id_rsa.pub  
--->Dockerfile

image4  
--->ssh-keys  
------>config  
------>id_rsa  
------>id_rsa.pub  
--->Dockerfile
```

Is there a way to remove this duplications ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Scratch` does not contain anything, better to use alpine as a base image and remove the below command from reusable section

```
RUN useradd -s /bin/bash -p $(openssl passwd -1 user) -d /home/user -m -G sudo user
USER user
```

As these commands vary from OS to OS(base image) and it will not work in alpine etc

So I will suggest something like

```
image1  
--->Dockerfile
image2  
--->Dockerfile
baseimage
--->ssh-keys  
------>config  
------>id_rsa  
------>id_rsa.pub  
--->Dockerfile
```

Desing base image

```
FROM alpine as sshconfig
WORKDIR /home/user

RUN mkdir -p /home/user/.ssh/ && \
    chmod 0700 /home/user/.ssh  && \
    touch /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys && \
    chmod 600 /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys && \
    touch /home/user/.ssh/config && \
    chmod 600 /home/user/.ssh/config
COPY ssh-keys/ /keys/
RUN cat /keys/id_rsa.pub >> /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys
RUN cat /keys/config >> /home/user/.ssh/config
```

Build this image

```
docker build -t sshconfig .
```

Now subsequent Docker Image will copy from this `sshconfig` Docker base image.

Image1

```
FROM ubuntu
# Add user
# change user

# copy ssh-config from base image
COPY --from=sshconfig /home/user/.ssh /home/user/.ssh

#for testing and verify keys
COPY --from=sshconfig /keys/ /keys/
# list keys copies form base image
RUN ls -lstrah /home/user/ /home/user/.ssh /keys/
```

Comment: Great, give it try and let me know

Comment: so I don't have to use [multi-stage-build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) ? in fact it does'nt work as beofre I have to test again

Comment: This is multi stage build but we just out base image to separate build directories to make thing resublale and avoid having copy in each folder

Comment: Using `alpine` just inflates the size of the base image and doesn't actually do anything useful for the other images. All the poster is doing is bundling files (which you don't need RUN operations for!)

Comment: sorry I didn't work on this since monday ... the copy is well done but `authorized_keys` and `config`are empty. Is this related to the `chmod 600` ?

Comment: yes that's it ... `COPY --from=sshconfig /keys/ /keys/` misses too

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into using a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) to serve as the base for all of your images and extend from there as needed; perhaps your base could be something like:

```
FROM scratch

# I like to keep all my image files under a single directory
COPY rootfs/ /
```

Then, in your other `Dockerfile`s:

```
FROM your-base-image AS base
FROM openjdk:8

COPY --from=base / /

[...]
```

Downside is there are only certain actions that will work as you expect in a multi-stage build, but copying files is one that should.

Comment: what would be `scratch` ? I don`t know the underlying os of `openjdk`, `mongo` or `ssh` and I do no have control on them !

Comment: [Here's an explanation: https://hub.docker.com/_/scratch/](https://hub.docker.com/_/scratch/)

Comment: when I use `scratch` I get this error `OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/sh\": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory": unknown`, which I don't have when extending `alpine` ... do you know why ?

Comment: The `FROM scratch` needs to be _prior_ to another `FROM ...` -- please read the link in my answer for details. If you're still having troubles you'll likely want to open a new question.